# Static invariants with tagless final

Tags: sql, haskell, types, dsl

### **TL;DR** How can I encode static invariants that are possible with GADTs when using a tagless encoding?

I am building a dsl on top of a SQL like language, with the goals of rounding out some of the rough edges, type safety and minor query optimization.

In my first pass I used GADT's to enforce several restrictions that the target language would execute but the output was in most cases garbage. Namely columns of mixed length in select statements like

```
select mean x, x by date, time from tbl
```

I prevent these mixed selections by tagging columns as either Selections (vectors) or Reductions (scalars) and thus the compiler can statically prevent these operations. I never did figure out how to prevent selecting from a groupby, however.

The next feature to scratch off is to add type checking to the column arithmetic operations, my first bad idea was to add another phantom type to carry the column type. This wont work as it would break my Schema type and I could no longer select columns of mixed types. This led me to think a tagless embedding of Columns might be appropriate as I could then get the appropriate representation (type, size, etc.) depending on the context. The downside is that this would appear to defer all the invariants I want to encode til run-time. To illustrate this here is rough pseudo code for `add` in the GADT and tagless approaches.

```
-- | GADT
add :: Column ty s1 -> Column ty s2
add a b = BinExpr Add a b

-- | Tagless
add :: Column c => c -> c -> c
add a b | (a :: ColType) == (b :: ColType) = binexpr Add a b
        | TypeMismatch a b
```

The GADT approach also has the benefit of being able to specify `Num ty => ...` to prevent addition on columns of strings. This type of issue would seem to propagate through all my code as I now have to defer to runtime checking to ensure prevention of `Select`s of mixed size or `Group` only working on a `Query Selection`. So my question is: Can I somehow retain the static guarantees of GADTs while using the flexibility of a Tagless style?

**My current GADTs**

```
{-# LANGUAGE
    GADTs
  , DataKinds
  , TypeFamilies #-}

-- Kinds

-- | State Tags
--   These constructors are promoted to the kind level to be used as 
--   phantom types to enforce static query invariants. For instance
--   these are strategically used to prevent selecting from a Groupby
--   or preventing selection of mixlengthed columns

data Sz = Selection | Reduction deriving Show

--------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Schema 

data Schema = Schema { 
    name :: Maybe String, 
    spec :: [Column Selection] 
} deriving Eq

--------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Column Datatype

data Column (a :: Sz) where
    Column  :: String -> Column Selection
    Assign  :: String -> Column a -> Column a
    FKey    :: String -> Schema -> Column Selection
    BinExpr :: BinOp  -> Column a -> Column b -> Column (ColOp a b)
    LogExpr :: LogOp  -> Column a -> Column b -> Column Selection
    AggExpr :: AggOp  -> Column Selection -> Column Reduction

type family ColOp (a :: Sz) (b :: Sz) where
    -- | If both sides a scalar then output
    --   is still a scalar, otherwise return
    --   a vector, as we can perform the op
    --   elemwise or brodcast a scalar across
    --   the vector
    ColOp Reduction Reduction = Reduction
    ColOp a         b         = Selection 

--------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Query types

class Tabular repr where
    meta  ::  repr (a :: Sz) -> Schema

data Query (a :: Sz) where
    Table  :: Schema -> Query Selection
    Select :: (Tabular t, Show (t b)) => [Column a] -> t b -> Query Selection
    Where  :: (Tabular t, Show (t Selection)) => [Column Selection] -> t Selection -> Query Selection
    Group  :: (Tabular t, Show (t Selection)) => [Column Selection] -> t Selection -> Query Reduction
```

**Tagless Column Prototype**

```
{-# language FlexibleInstances #-}

data Sz = Selection | Reduction 
    deriving Show

data ColType 
    = Int | Float | String | Bool 
    | TypeMismatch ColType ColType 
    deriving (Show, Eq)

data BinOp = Add  | Mul
data AggOp = Mean | Count

-- Tagless AST
class Show repr => Column repr where
    column  :: String -> ColType -> repr
    assign  :: String -> repr    -> repr
    binExpr :: BinOp  -> repr    -> repr  -> repr
    aggExpr :: AggOp  -> repr    -> repr

-- Show Instances
instance Show BinOp where
    show Add = " + "
    show Mul = " * "

instance Show AggOp where 
    show Mean  = "mean "
    show Count = "count "

-- I Would like to bring these into the type level (ie performed statically)
opSz :: Sz -> Sz -> Sz
opSz Reduction Reduction = Reduction
opSz a         b         = Selection

typeCheck :: ColType -> ColType -> ColType 
typeCheck a b | a == b = a
              | otherwise = TypeMismatch a b

-- Tagless Interpreters
-- | Stringify
instance Column ([Char]) where 
    column  s t   = s
    assign  s c   = s ++ ": " ++ show c
    binExpr o l r = l ++ show o ++ r
    aggExpr op l  = show op ++ l

-- | Column Size
instance Column Sz where 
    column  s t   = Selection
    assign  s c   = c :: Sz
    binExpr o l r = opSz l r
    aggExpr op l  = Reduction

-- | Column Type
instance Column ColType where 
    column s t    = t
    assign s c    = c :: ColType
    binExpr o l r = typeCheck l r
    aggExpr o l   = l :: ColType

add :: Column c => c -> c -> c
add l r = binExpr Add l r

columns :: Column c => [c]
columns = [ column "a" Float
          , column "b" Int
          , column "c" String ]

a :: Column c => c
a = columns !! 0

b :: Column c => c
b = columns !! 1

-- add a b :: ColType => TypeMismatch Float Int
```

**Edit:** I can get similar behavior by adding a type parameter to the class

```
class Column repr where 
    column  :: String -> repr Selection
    assign  :: String -> repr (a :: Sz) -> repr (a :: Sz)
    binExpr :: BinOp  -> repr (a :: Sz) -> repr (b :: Sz) -> repr (OpSz a b)
    aggExpr :: AggOp  -> repr Selection -> repr Reduction
```

But I am still curious how I can define an interpreter of the ast that brings `ColType` to the type level such that I can define `add :: C t -> C t -> C t` so `add a :: (C String) b :: (C Int)` doesn't typecheck

Comment: First off, getting database typing right in Haskell seems to be fairly painful. It's just not a terribly good fit for Haskell's type system. Secondly, my limited experience suggests that GADTs are easier to think about than tagless final encodings. Even if you want the latter, it can be easier to start with the former and transform.

Comment: Oleg [covered this](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/#in-fin). Basically, mimic the GADT constructors as methods of the type class *including the type parameters*.  I'm not sure why the `Column` GADT is allowed to be of kind `Sz -> *` but the `Column` class classifies types of kind `*`.

Comment: I can certainly do that (see edit). I think what I want though is an interpreter for the tagless ast that promotes the column type (Int, Float, etc) to the type level when convenient such that I can define add with a signature like `add :: C t -> C t -> C t`